# Concurrency behavior of AWS Lambda

Tags: java, concurrency, aws-lambda

Suppose I have a code like this.

```
public class MyHandler {
    private Foo foo;
    public void handler(InputStream request, OutputStream response, Context context) {
       ...
    }
}
```

**Foo foo** takes care of creating pooled database connections.

I am trying to understand how this works with AWS Lambda. If I am understanding correctly, **foo** gets shared across multiple invocations. The first one takes more time because it has to load into the container and subsequent ones would be faster since **foo** is already initialized. This would be the case until my handler gets kicked out after a period of inactivity.

So, for  sequential invocations, would it use the same object, would it have access to /tmp created in earlier function call ?

What about parallel invocations ? Would it duplicate the entire container, because as per the docs, each lambda  function should execute in its own container, its own resources and its own /tmp ?

If the handler is going to get kicked out after inactivity, is there a callback function in Java that I can call to close out all opened pooled connections ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, for sequential invocations, would it use the same object, would it
>   have access to /tmp created in earlier function call ?

Yes it would use the same object. Yes it would have access to `/tmp` created in earlier function call.

> What about parallel invocations ? Would it duplicate the entire
>   container, because as per the docs, each lambda function should
>   execute in its own container, its own resources and its own /tmp ?

Parallel invocations would occur in separate containers. A single container only handles one invocation at a time. So yes the entire container would be duplicated, and each container has its own `/tmp`.

> If the handler is going to get kicked out after inactivity, is there a
>   callback function in Java that I can call to close out all opened
>   pooled connections ?

No there is no callback you can use to handle this. Your function will be in a suspended state when the container is eventually removed due to inactivity.

Comment: So in case of parallel invocations, there will be usual overhead of creating the database connection when the duplication of the container happens ? So that means, there is no use of creating a pooled connection for AWS Lambda ?

Comment: In case of parallel executions where there isn't enough containers already initiated, then yes there will be the overhead of creating a database connection for new containers that are created. If you have continued parallel invocations over some time then those containers will be reused, which means there is a very good reason for creating the DB connection outside the handler. However if you are using a connection pool inside a Lambda function I think you would only want the pool to be of size 1.

Comment: Thanks. That clears things. Basically, its like creating a direct connection to DB and not a pooled one. If I am understanding correctly, there is no guarantee the second invocation will get access to data stored in `/tmp` by first invocation in parallel environment even though the 2 invocations were sequential.

Wondering the real use case of `/tmp`

Comment: Correct, there is no guarantee.

Comment: Why would we be using `/tmp` if the real and stable use case is for one invocation ?

Comment: Also, there is no way to gracefully close the connection to the DB in this case?

Comment: I don't know what "real and stable use case" you are referring to exactly. If your function is being called more than once every 5-10 minutes or so then you will get container reuse. If you are getting container reuse then you will get a performance benefit on subsequent calls by reusing database connections, reusing `/tmp` files, etc.

Comment: You are correct that if you are reusing DB connections across invocations then there is no way to gracefully close the connection.

Comment: Regarding DB I guess I'm left with 2 options - setup connection and tear down for every request OR setup connection outside handler and let RDS take care of terminating hung connection.  When I say real and stable use case for `/tmp`, I mean, I can only use what's stored in `/tmp` in the second invocation if the call goes to the same container, which is not guaranteed in a parallel environment. Hence using `/tmp` for cache data is also unreliable. So I'm actually wondering about it's real purpose in case of parallel environment.

Comment: `/tmp` is not there primarily as a cache. It is there as the only place on the file system that you can write to. The most common use case is to download an image file to `/tmp` perform some work such as resizing the image, and then copy it back to S3. However you seem to be hung up on thinking that "parallel" means that containers will never be reused, or that you can't "depend" on reuse or something. As long as your function is being called a lot then whatever you are caching in `/tmp` will be there for the majority of the calls, and so reuse would speed up the majority of calls.